# Erase an element in std::list using pointer not iterator

Tags: c++, list, sorting, pointers, priority-queue

As the title stated, I'm using `std::list`. I have objects in `master.list`. Then I use a `std::priority_queue` or whatever, called `sortedList` to store pointers to the objects in my `master.list` and it's all sorted in this `sortedList` now. Because it's sorted, I can remove them using `sortedList.pop()`.

The question is how can I elegantly remove objects back in my original `master.list`

I want to use `erase`, but it only take iterator while I just have pointer. Because I want the speed, I really don't want to use `remove` here.

Comment: Don't store pointers in the priority queue, and instead store list iterators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not store iterators in the priority queue instead of raw pointers?  Since you are using list you do not need to worry about iterator invalidation.  Then you can just use `std::list::erase`.  The overhead of storing an iterator should be negligible since it just holds a pointer to the list node.

```
typedef std::list<T> MyListT;
typedef std::priority_queue<MyListT::iterator> MyQueueT;

MyListT myList;
MyQueueT myQueue;

myList.push_front(T());
myQueue.push_back(myList.begin());

// Later...

MyListT::iterator itr = myQueue.front();
myQueue.pop_back();
myList.erase(itr);
```

Comment: The priority queue will need a comparator, but the `typedef`s here eliminate all the "ugly syntax" downsides.